# Logic Level MOSFET Behaving Unexpectedly Driving PWM Signal to PSU

Tags: mosfet, pwm, logic-level

I am trying to control a MeanWell dimmable PSU with an Arduino. Since I do not want to exceed 60% of the output of the MeanWell, I want to use a 0 to 6V PWM signal. I figured a quick and dirty way to do this would be to use a logic-level MOSFET. As the title suggests, I ran into some unexpected behavior when probing my circuit with a multimeter. In the circuit diagram, all the COMM grounds are connected. Here are my observations:

- The voltage between G and S on the MOSFET varied between 0 and 5V, as
  expected.
- The voltage between D and S varied between 0 and 0.1V. I was
  expecting 0 to 6V.
- The load across the MeanWell leads varied between 5.9 and 6V. Again,
  I expected 0 to 6V.
- When not using the MOSFET, and applying 0 to 5V PWM to control the
  MeanWell PSU, it worked as expected. The MeanWell would output 50%
  power to its load when the 5V PWM was applied at full duty cycle.

I have a feeling that, for whatever reason, the MOSFET is creating a 0.1V voltage drop on the 6V path instead of opening/closing the path. However, I don't know why. I thought the MOSFET would cycle between very high (almost open circuit) resistance and very low resistance based on the PWM input on the gate.

Am I doing something silly with this circuit? What gives?

[image: see the circuit diagram]

Comment: There is nothing to pull the "load" (control input) high when the MOSFET is off. I suggest a 100R resistor from Drain to +6V. (1K or 10K would do if that wasn't such a huge FET).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll give it a shot. I'm assuming a 1-10k resistor would draw more current than is necessary?

Comment: Opposite way round. 1 or 10K would draw less current, and increase the rise time of the signal.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Makes sense. Unfortunately, adding the 100 ohm resistor between the drain and +6V did not fix the problem. The MOSFET is more or less behaving the same way it did before.

Comment: @BrianDrummond nevermind, I figured it out. I had the drain and the source wired backwards the whole time. Sometimes, even after checking something three or four times, I won't notice a dumb error like this one until the next morning. Thanks again for responding to my post!

Comment: Ah the body diode. I would have expected the 100 ohm pullup to give somewhere over 0.5V with the FET off.